# How fast to derive new features (pandas) shift one period or n periods at same time? (Performance issue)

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a dataframe with some continuos freatures (about 14), and I need to derivate more 14 (shift 1 period of hour) until n hours.

Supposing that I need until 6 hours before, so I will have more 84 columns (14*6).

For example, **prcp** (precipitation) derivates **prcp_1**, **prcp_2**, ... **prcp_6**, and the same thing for the others variables.

I was using this function:

```
def derive_nth_hour_feature(df, feature, N):  
    rows = df.shape[0]
    nth_prior_measurements = [None]*N + [df[feature][i-N] for i in range(N, rows)]
    col_name = "{}_{}".format(feature, N)
    df[col_name] = np.nan
    df.loc[:][col_name] = nth_prior_measurements

NON_DER = ['wsid','elvt','lat', 'lon', 'yr', 'mo', 'da', 'hr']

for feature in dfm.columns:
    if feature not in NON_DER:
        for h in range(1,7):
            derive_nth_day_feature(dfm, feature, h)
```

Work fine when the base have few records like ~ 100.000. But a have millions of records (~ 10 millions).

The result expected is like this: (derivating the prcp, stp and temp in 3 periods):

[image]

My main problem is the performance, spend a lots of time to process. The complexity is high 14^6*rows. So a need another approach.

Any sugestion?

Here a partial base (with one weather station):[wsid_329.csv.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NWUMkh0tHouOT8LMlv5t7nmcoI8Y4w6w)

Comment: I improved avoid the  SettingWithCopyWarning. Changing the line   col_name = "{}_{}".format(feature, N) to   df[col_name] = np.nan and    df.loc[:][col_name] = nth_prior_measurements. But is not so efficient.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data.  Paste it in your question as text and format it as code.

Comment: Is not a image of code. Is a image of an output and I tried to post, but wasn't good to see because is matrix and the space isn't large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my perfomance issue using a personalized function based on **dataframe.shift**:

> DataFrame.shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0)[source]
>
> ```
> Shift index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq
> ```

This my function:

```
def df_derived_by_shift(df,lag=0,NON_DER=[]):
    df = df.copy()

    if not lag:
        return df

    cols ={}
    for i in range(1,lag+1):
        for x in list(df.columns):
            if x not in NON_DER:
                if not x in cols:
                    cols[x] = ['{}_{}'.format(x, i)]
                else:
                    cols[x].append('{}_{}'.format(x, i))

    for k,v in cols.items():
        columns = v
        dfn = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=columns, index=df.index)    
        i = 1
        for c in columns:
            dfn[c] = df[k].shift(periods=i)
            i+=1
        df = pd.concat([df, dfn], axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])

    return df
```

An example of use:

```
NON_DER = ['wsid','elvt','lat', 'lon', 'yr', 'mo', 'da', 'hr']

r = df_derived_by_shift(dfm,3,NON_DER)
r.head(3)
```

The result:

[image]